# Magento category filter by custom attributes

Tags: magento, categories

I have added custom attributes to categories in Magento, now I need to select categories with these attributes filter in the custom module. Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 3):

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_code_here', 'value_here');
$categories->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', 2);//if you want only children of a specific category
    foreach ($categories as $category){
        //do something with $category
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response.Where should I pass category id ? I have  parent categories and need child categories by attribute filter.Right now I am using $cat =  =Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(2);
$subcats = $cat->getChildren();

Comment: $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('category_color', 'Blue');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', 3);//if you want only children of a specific category
echo '<pre>';
print_r($collection); or  print_r($categories);  //both giving error
echo '</pre>'; giving "Fatal error: Call to a member function addAttributeToFilter() on a non-object "

Comment: I have removed everything from page and put only above code,same error.can you please just tell direct db query to get child categories of a parent category with these filters ?

Comment: Ok.. I saw my mistake and fixed it. You can try it now. I don't know the sql query to do it, and there is no need for it.. It's too complex.

Comment: Not getting any record.Thanks for your help.if you have any further suggestion please let me know.Regards

Answer (score 1):

Never mind,I got the solution.i just had to add below line of code  and it worked

**->addAttributeToFilter('door_material', 53)**

where **"door_material"** is **custom attribute** for category and **"53"** is selected option id in back-end.I hope it will help someone.